# Scrape dynmically rendered by scroll objects

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, selenium, web-scraping

I would like to scrape linkedin's job section, for example the following link:

https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/search/?f_TPR=r86400&geoId=105080838&keywords=Full%20Stack&location=New%20York%2C%20United%20States

As you can see, as soon as you scroll to to bottom the page loads more jobs.

The effect I am looking for is, I want somehow to get an answer from the site after it scrolled all the way to the bottom, containing all the possible jobs, for parsing I will use cheerio.

What I managed to do using js and nodejs is to get only the first page, but not more.

Answer (score 0):

the first step would be to get the number of full-stack jobs returned from your search:

[image: number of job results]

now that we know the attributes of the element, we can grab him using cheerio,

```
let number_of_jobs = $("h1>small[class='jobs-search-results-list__text']").text()
```

now, as you mentioned,

> The way that LinkedIn job postings work is loading more jobs if you scroll down the browser bar

***but,*** when you drag the bar a few times, it will not load automatically, whereas you would have to click a button that says 'See more jobs'.

So we will take advantage of that and use a `try`/`except` method. The number of jobs returned from our query will determine the number of times we will drag the handler using [selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/) (we cant use cheerio here since it's an HTML parser). You can also use [puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer) [phantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/).

```
let i = 2
while (i <= int(no_of_jobs/25)+1): 
    wd.execute_script(“window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);”)
     i = i + 1
     try:
     wd.find_element_by_xpath
(‘/html/body/main/div/section/button’).click()
     time.sleep(5)
     except:
         pass
         time.sleep(5)
```

---

To get the jobs list, we would use the class name - `jobs-search-results__list`, which is exclusive to the jobs list, and we'll loop through its `li` elements for each job.

[image: jobs list]

again, using selenium:

```
let jobs_list = wd.find_element_by_class_name(‘jobs-search__results-list’)
let jobs = jobs_list.find_elements_by_tag_name(‘li’)
```

---

You can check the length of `jobs` and the variable `number_of_jobs` we set at the beginning to ensure you got everything.

And that's all.

---

You can use any chrome controller API with this logic, I would recommend puppeteer, but here I used selenium since you used it as a tag.